# script doesnt run while runing through crontab -e

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

So i have a script for waking up my computer using rtc... The script manually works fine but when i am trying to run it through crontab -e it doesnt work.  I am not very familiar with cron so maby i am doing something wrong.

at this time i use the command:

```
@reboot /nikos/script/auto.sh
```

just to try and see if it is working...a tried some other ways(using path and some others but nothing work)

THe code of the script

```
#!/bin/bash 
sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm" 
sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 420 minutes'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"
```

any help is apreciated

EDIT:
in order to see if it worked i run:

```
cat /proc/driver/rtc
```

and i see that it rtc alarm is not enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one thing right off. You need to provide absolute paths to /bin/sh, /bin/echo and /bin/date

Putting absolute paths in scripts executed in cron solves most problems. If your scripts run fine on the command line but not in cron that is usually the culprit.

/bin/sh -c "/bin/echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"

/bin/sh -c "/bin/echo /bin/date '+%s' -d '+ 420 minutes' > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"

Answers to another post at stackexchange also makes mention of cron having issues with @reboot scripts for many reasons. Check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root

It may be worth your while to run it by adding it to a bootup script such as /etc/rc.d/rc.local instead of using cron. You will still have best results providing absolute paths to commands to make sure they are accessible.

Also: test if @reboot is working properly on your system. Not all versions of cron execute that properly. Add this script to test:  @reboot /bin/echo "@reboot works" > /tmp/reboot_test

If your target directory is not available at boot time by the time your reboot script starts that will also cause a problem.

Comment: try typing the command by itself: /bin/echo /bin/date '+%s' -d '+ 420 minutes'

Comment: it is possible your directory is not loaded yet when the script runs. see if you can get it to do this in /tmp like so /bin/sh -c "/bin/echo /bin/date '+%s' -d '+ 420 minutes' > /tmp/waketest"

Comment: check them like so: cat /bin/waketest and also cat  /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm to see if they are putting the data there (test manually and also after cron attempts)

Comment: You need to do that before you can check the proc of rtc (if they are putting the data there and rtc is still not running then it is not the script that is the issue, it is possibly a timing issue)

Comment: this didnt do it either...:(
ok i will try that  too and i will let you know

Comment: did this work on the command line (i tested it on my box just now): /bin/echo /bin/date '+%s' -d '+ 420 minutes'

Comment: also this: /bin/echo /bin/date '+%s' -d '+ 420 minutes' > /tmp/waketest  (then do a cat /tmp/waketest to see if it put the file in the tmp directory)

Comment: I added a few points in edit above for you. If the scripts load and place commands in /tmp but not in your rtc directory, then you may elect to add a sleep command to be sure everything is loaded before you try running your script. If you are not running your command as root, attempt that as well.

Comment: Mistype in my comment above to test the tmp code: it should say cat /tmp/waketest (not /bin/waketest)